# Undefined Property on Controller from file array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, variables, undefined

I'm new to php and to stack so I beg you some patience with me.
I'm learning with Laravel framework at university and the next code gives me this message:

> Undefined property:
>   App\Http\Controllers\CatalogController::$arrayPeliculas

I will show you the code now:

**-CatalogController.php**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CatalogController extends Controller{

    public function getIndex(){
         return view('catalog.index',
          array('arrayPeliculas'=>$this->arrayPeliculas));
    }

    public function getShow($id){

        return view('catalog.show', array('id'=>$id));
    }

    public function getCreate(){

        return view('catalog.create');
    }

    public function getEdit($id){

        return view('catalog.edit', array('id'=>$id));
    }
}
```

**-index.blade.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        @extends('layouts.master')

        @section('content')

        <div class="row">

          @foreach( $arrayPeliculas as $key => $pelicula )
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 text-center">

            <a href="{{ url('/catalog/show/' . $key ) }}">
              <img src="{{$pelicula['poster']}}" style="height:200px"/>
              <h4 style="min-height:45px;margin:5px 0 10px 0">
                {{$pelicula['title']}}
              </h4>
            </a>

          </div>
          @endforeach

        </div>

        @stop
      </div>
      <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**-array_peliculas.php**

```
private $arrayPeliculas = array(
    array(
        'title' => 'El padrino',
        'year' => '1972', 
        'director' => 'Francis Ford Coppola', 
        'poster' => 'http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjEyMjcyNDI4MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDA5Mzg3OA@@._V1_SX214_AL_.jpg', 
        'rented' => false, 
        'synopsis' => 'Don Vito Corleone (Marlon Brando) es el respetado y temido jefe de una de las cinco familias de la mafia de Nueva York. Tiene cuatro hijos: Connie (Talia Shire), el impulsivo Sonny (James Caan), el pusilánime Freddie (John Cazale) y Michael (Al Pacino), que no quiere saber nada de los negocios de su padre. Cuando Corleone, en contra de los consejos de \'Il consigliere\' Tom Hagen (Robert Duvall), se niega a intervenir en el negocio de las drogas, el jefe de otra banda ordena su asesinato. Empieza entonces una violenta y cruenta guerra entre las familias mafiosas.'
    )
```

This array is more large but for an example its ok. Can anybody help me?
Just for info, the route.php file works fine.

Comment: there is no $arrayPeliculas variable declared within your CatalogController class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error comes from this line:

```
 array('arrayPeliculas'=>$this->arrayPeliculas));
```

`$arrayPeliculas` does not exist in your controller. You may add it like this:

`private $arrayPelliculas = [...];`

Directly in your controller.

To load the array from a 'different' file, you can create a trait or a helper like this.

**Helper**

File location: `app/Helpers/Peliculas.php`. You create the folder and the file yourself. Don't forget to add .php extension.

```
<?php 
namespace App\Helpers;

class Pelicula 
{
    public static function getPeliculas()
    {
        return [
            [
                'title' => 'El padrino',
                'year' => '1972', 
                'director' => 'Francis Ford Coppola', 
                'poster' => 'http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjEyMjcyNDI4MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDA5Mzg3OA@@._V1_SX214_AL_.jpg', 
                'rented' => false, 
                'synopsis' => 'Don Vito Corleone (Marlon Brando) es el respetado y temido jefe de una de las cinco familias de la mafia de Nueva York. Tiene cuatro hijos: Connie (Talia Shire), el impulsivo Sonny (James Caan), el pusilánime Freddie (John Cazale) y Michael (Al Pacino), que no quiere saber nada de los negocios de su padre. Cuando Corleone, en contra de los consejos de \'Il consigliere\' Tom Hagen (Robert Duvall), se niega a intervenir en el negocio de las drogas, el jefe de otra banda ordena su asesinato. Empieza entonces una violenta y cruenta guerra entre las familias mafiosas.'
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Then in your controller 
Add to the top `use App\Helpers\Pelicula;` and update the `getIndex()` function like this :

```
return view('catalog.index', array('arrayPeliculas'=> Pelicula::getPeliculas()));
```

The advantage is that you can now access that array from anywhere. Even directly from your views without passing through a controller. To access it globally, you can add an alias to `config/app.php` like this:

```
'aliases' => [
    ...
    'Pelicula' => App\Helpers\Pelicula::class,
];
```

Then anywhere in your projet, just do `Pelicula::getPeliculas()` and it will give you that array;

Comment: First of all thanks for the fast reply.
The problem is i need to load that array (arrayPeliculas) from another file necessarily for my project. Althought i added your code and the error persist.

Comment: where is the file located ? If you want, you can make a `Helper` which is like a class and will contain just that array. If the file is out of your laravel project, then it might be more complicated to load it. If you want to load it from Laravel, I can update my answer to show you how to do it.

Comment: Yes! I want to load it from inside my Laravel project. In fact, the route is:
Laravelproject/resources/views/partials/array_peliculas.php.

Comment: Ok I see. You cannot load it as as a view. Views are just to display data. I change my answer to show you how to load array from another file.

Comment: Yep of course, my purpose is to send that array from that controller to index.blade.php where ill show it.

Comment: I followed your answer step by step with no errors, and now i get this message: "Class 'App\Helpers\Pelicula' not found"
It seems it can't find any file i could create, even if its in the root of the project.
Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Done, the message throws the same. Tomorrow ill try to compile this on a Windows machine (now im on Mac) and i'll comment the results.
Again, thanks a lot for your time :)

Comment: Shoudn't make any difference. I work on mac. But yeah, you are welcome. It was my pleasure to help.

Comment: I expected as you said that in a Windows machine won't work, cause the issue could be the same in code but for some reason... it works with your code!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong. You can't call your array using `$this->arrayPeliculas`.
In your `CatalogController.php` make a function with the name `Peliculas`:

```
protected function peliculas(){

return 
array(
    'title' => 'El padrino',
    'year' => '1972', 
    'director' => 'Francis Ford Coppola', 
    'poster' => 'http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjEyMjcyNDI4MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDA5Mzg3OA@@._V1_SX214_AL_.jpg', 
    'rented' => false, 
    'synopsis' => 'Don Vito Corleone (Marlon Brando) es el respetado y temido jefe de una de las cinco familias de la mafia de Nueva York. Tiene cuatro hijos: Connie (Talia Shire), el impulsivo Sonny (James Caan), el pusilánime Freddie (John Cazale) y Michael (Al Pacino), que no quiere saber nada de los negocios de su padre. Cuando Corleone, en contra de los consejos de \'Il consigliere\' Tom Hagen (Robert Duvall), se niega a intervenir en el negocio de las drogas, el jefe de otra banda ordena su asesinato. Empieza entonces una violenta y cruenta guerra entre las familias mafiosas.'
);
}
```

Now, you can call this new function using `$this->arrayPeliculas` in your `getIndex`